# Nmap NTP scanning monlist

Tags: nmap, ntp

I'm trying to find if an NTP server allows or disallows usage of the "monlist" command with Nmap, but I haven't found how to do that.

I found the following script : https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ntp-monlist.html

But I have no clue how to use / install it correctly.

**UPDATE :**

Result with the first command on a random NTP server :

```
  Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-04 13:02 Paris, Madrid (heure d?été)

  Nmap scan report for 213.140.255.15

  Host is up (0.069s latency).

  PORT    STATE SERVICE

  123/udp open  ntp



  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.50 seconds
```

With the second one :

```
  Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-04 13:04 Paris, Madrid (heure d?été)

  Nmap scan report for 213.140.255.15

  Host is up (0.070s latency).

  PORT    STATE SERVICE

  123/udp open  ntp



  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.32 seconds
```

But I'm not seeing any output on Monlist being enabled or not on the server.
Is it perhaps because it's disabled ?

Answer (score 3):

```
nmap --script +ntp-monlist -p 123 -sU <ip or hostname>
```

or perhaps

```
nmap --script ntp-monlist -p 123 -sUV <ip or hostname>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated the main question with the results of the commands.

Comment: Yeah, it looks broken. Try it with `-d` and `--script-trace`

Comment: I tried what you said here is the result (I pasted it into pastebin because it's long) http://pastebin.com/umZPcxxG I'm still not sure about the output. Thanks for your help!